# An appbundles binary could not be found (Design Automation V3)

Tags: c#, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to post a workitem using design automation v3. I managed to create an appbundle and an activity, but when I post a workitem I get this exception :

The server returned the non-success status code 400 (Bad Request).
More error details:
{"appbundles":["An appbundles binary could not be found.  Make sure your apps were uploaded correctly.\nParameter name: appbundles"]}.

What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you upload the module file? See here for details: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/reference/http/AppPackages-Operations.GetUploadUrl-GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually indicates that you forgot to upload your zip file. I recommend that you you use our [.net sdk](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation). It has some helpful wrappers that make this easier. See [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/ApiClient.cs#L62).

Comment: I did upload it. But I did it wrong. I tought a simple PUT would do it, like with Design Automation V2. But no, the multipart content is required.

Comment: Yes, we use multipart upload is used so that we can limit the size of the zip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is new update for upload zip appbunle

```
 RestClient uploadClient = new RestClient(newAppVersion.UploadParameters.EndpointURL);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.POST)
        {
            AlwaysMultipartFormData = true
        };
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in newAppVersion.UploadParameters.FormData)
            request.AddParameter(x.Key, x.Value);
        request.AddFile("file", _configuration.PackageZipPath);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        var result = uploadClient.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Uploaded app bundle status: " + result.StatusCode);
        if (result.IsSuccessful == false)
        {
            await _designAutomation.DeleteAppBundleAsync(_configuration.AppName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            throw new Exception("Cannot upload app bundle to endpoint" + newAppVersion.UploadParameters.EndpointURL);
        }
```

I'm still have same problem with new package version of Autodesk and finally I'm also fixed my problem by downgrade version of nuget :

```
<PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge" Version="1.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation" Version="5.1.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a sample code to upload the ZIP AppBundle:

```
        RestClient uploadClient = new RestClient(newAppVersion.UploadParameters.EndpointURL);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.POST);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in newAppVersion.UploadParameters.FormData) request.AddParameter(x.Key, x.Value);
        request.AddFile("file", packageZipPath);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        await uploadClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

From [Learn Forge Tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io), see [code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/master/forgesample/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs#L215).